# $\omega_1(p) \le \omega_2(p)$ for all projections $p$ implies $\omega_1 \le \omega_2$.

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M\subseteq B(H)$ be a von Neumann algebra. Let $\omega_1, \omega_2$ be functionals on $M$ satisfying
$$\omega_1(p) \le \omega_2(p) \quad (*)$$
for all projections $p \in M$. Is it true that $\omega_1 \le \omega_2$, i.e. that $(*)$ holds for all positive elements $p \in M$ as well?

I think I need some decomposition result that says that a positive elements is a linear combination with positive coefficients of projections. Do we have such result?

Comment: Yes, we have such a result, it's called the spectral theorem. You probably need some continuity assumption on $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, though.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks! What kind of continuity assumptions? I only assume $\omega_1, \omega_2$ to be norm-continuous.

Comment: That's enough, you can always approximate positive elements by positive linear combinations of projections - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in M$ be positive and $e$ its spectral measure (the projection-valued version). By the spectral theorem,
$$
x=\int_{[0\|x\|]}\lambda\,de(\lambda).
$$
For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a tagged partition $(I_k,\lambda_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ of $[0,\|x\|]$ such that $|\lambda-\lambda_k|<\epsilon$ for $\lambda\in I_k$. Then $y=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k 1_{I_k}(x)$ is a positive linear combination of projections in $M$ and
$$
\|x-y\|=\left\lVert\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{[0,\|x\|]}(\lambda-\lambda_k)\,d e(\lambda)\right\rVert\leq \epsilon.
$$
In particular, $x$ is the norm limit of positive linear combinations of projections.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: You're right, I corrected this.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.